# ClientHandlerException in REST client only when executing jar file

Tags: java, rest, maven, jar

I have set up a REST Webservice and a Client. The Webservice is deployed on a Glassfish server. If I run the main class of the client out of netbeans everything works fine. Now I use Maven to create a executable jar file and if I try to run this jar file I get the following exception message:

```
21.07.2013 13:40:05 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SCHWERWIEGEND: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
21.07.2013 13:40:05 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SCHWERWIEGEND: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider
  com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomEntryProvider

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:561)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:517)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:684)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
    at de.movienexuscmd.MovieNexusWebserviceClient.getXml(MovieNexusWebserviceClient.java:52)
    at de.movienexuscmd.App.run(App.java:20)
    at de.movienexuscmd.App.main(App.java:16)
```

Now I really don't know why this Exception appears only when trying to execute the jar file.  Hope anyone can help.

My Webservice looks like:

```
@Path("MovieNexus")
public class MovieNexusWebService {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

private MovieNexusFrontController frontController = null;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of MovieNexusWebService
 */
public MovieNexusWebService() {
    frontController = new MovieNexusFrontController();
}

/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of
 * de.webservice.MovieNexusWebService
 *
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getXml() {
    return frontController.getRandomMovie().getMovieName();
}

/**
 * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of MovieNexusWebService
 *
 * @param content representation for the resource
 * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
 */
@PUT
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void putXml(String content) {
}
}
```

The Client:

```
public class MovieNexusWebserviceClient {

private WebResource webResource;

private Client client;

private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:17589/MovieNexusWebservice/webresources";

public MovieNexusWebserviceClient() {
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
    client = Client.create(config);
    webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("MovieNexus");
}

public String getXml() throws UniformInterfaceException {
    WebResource resource = webResource;
    return resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);
}

public void putXml(Object requestEntity) throws UniformInterfaceException {
    webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(requestEntity);
}

public void close() {
    client.destroy();
}
}
```

greetings

Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by myself after hours of thinking and trying. The Problem was the creation of the executable jar by maven. Some dependencies missed in it, so i changed the plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>mainclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: If you create your executable file like that, all libraries are beeing placed in lib directory. If you want to run the jar file, the lib directory has to be in the same directory. I'm not sure if this a good solution, sure there are possibilities to solve this in a more efficient way. Feel free to post one :)